# Custom Login Page through LDAP in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, ldap

I want to implement LDAP authentication in my Spring Boot app. I have configuration class as below:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//@Value("${ad.domain}")
private String AD_DOMAIN;

//@Value("${ad.url}")
private String AD_URL;

WebSecurityConfig() {
    AD_DOMAIN = "domain.com";
    AD_URL = "ldap://URL";
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin().permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN, AD_URL);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    return provider;
  }
}
```

controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String user = auth.getName();
    return "Welcome to the home page "+ user;
}
```

And my pom file have dependencies as :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here all is working fine I am getting SpringBoot's default login page and Authentication is also working.
But now I want a **Custom login Page** for that in my WebSecurityConfig class I have done the following :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
}
```

where `/login` is my custom login page. But this is not working. I think that the AuthenticationManager is bind to the Spring's default login Page.

Can Someone suggest me, it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: suppose you refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-ldap) example on github. this [post](https://github.com/eddumelendez/ldap-spring-boot) is also a good place to start.

Comment: Sorry but these did not work for me. I have my ldap working for me the thing I need is how to reach my custom login page.

Comment: Could you fix it? Please help.